# Encoding url struggle

Tags: java, url, uri, resttemplate, encoder

I have a String url. The last part is a filter containg [ and ].

```
[{'field':'campaign.effective_status','operator':'IN','value':['ACTIVE']}]
```

No matter what I try, I cannot encode and send this as a valid URL or URI.

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand ''field''] with root cause
```

This is because of the [.

When I execute:

```
String response = restTemplate.getForObject(fbUrl, String.class);
```

It fails.

I tried adding the filter as variable.

```
String response = restTemplate.getForObject(fbUrl, String.class,"["+filter+"]");
```

It succeeds, but does not apply the filter.

When I use this,

```
fbUrl = fbUrl +URLEncoder.encode("[","UTF-8")+URLEncoder.encode(request.getFilters(),"UTF-8")+URLEncoder.encode("]","UTF-8");
```

I get:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_323342434/insights?level=campaign&fields=impressions&access_token=EAAUnOB1oiQgBAFeFVZCkOUC30JXgM9YHRl3C8ZCpubteRK9DtKbVSzgS8lR3N7zzZCCO7Bp7CIGCp7BqAmKbywDZAh71bcLW2YpQOQwZCx5v6xCJXXA6ZBx9QcjxNH5GCZBBXLeIhusnZAjZBdWocjhoOJXAYZCENPaUIN3kuukJQUggZDZD&time_increment=&sort=date_start_ascending&time_range[since]=2017-02-01&time_range[until]=2017-02-28&filtering=%5B%7B%27field%27%3A%27campaign.effective_status%27%2C%27operator%27%3A%27IN%27%2C%27value%27%3A%5B%27ACTIVE%27%5D%7D%5D

But then I get:

```
 org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request] with root cause
```

Any help is appreciated.

---

With help from realSkeptic I found the solution:

```
String baseUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/";
baseUrl = baseUrl + request.getAdvertiserId() + "/insights?level=" + request.getDimensions() +"&";
baseUrl = baseUrl +URLEncoder.encode("fields", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(request.getMetrics(), "UTF-8") +"&";
baseUrl = baseUrl +URLEncoder.encode("access_token", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(request.getAccessToken(), "UTF-8") +"&";
baseUrl = baseUrl +URLEncoder.encode("time_increment", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(request.getTimeIncrement(), "UTF-8") +"&";
baseUrl = baseUrl +URLEncoder.encode("sort", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(request.getSort(), "UTF-8") +"&";
baseUrl = baseUrl +URLEncoder.encode("time_range[since]", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(request.getStartDate(), "UTF-8") +"&";
baseUrl = baseUrl +URLEncoder.encode("time_range[until]", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(request.getEndDate(), "UTF-8") +"&";
baseUrl = baseUrl +URLEncoder.encode("filtering", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("["+request.getFilters()+"]", "UTF-8");
String response = restTemplate.getForObject(baseUrl, String.class);
```

Comment: At shallow glance, it seems that you are trying to pass a bad JSON - you are using single quotes instead of double quotes. What happens if you try it with double quotes?

Comment: Then Facebook will through a bad request.

Comment: This is the URL I am trying to construct. When I p[aste this in the browser it works. But for privacy reasons I changed the advertiser id.              

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_12304309488/insights?level=campaign&fields=impressions&access_token=EAAUnOB1oiQgBAFeFVZCkOUC30JXgM9YHRl3C8ZCpubteRK9DtKbVSzgS8lR3N7zzZCCO7Bp7CIGCOJXAYZCENPaUIN3kuukJQUggZDZD&time_increment=&sort=date_start_ascending&time_range[since]=2017-02-01&time_range[until]=2017-02-28&filtering=
[{'field':'campaign.effective_status','operator':'IN','value':['ACTIVE']}]

Comment: If it works when you put it in a browser, then you need to URLEncode each parameter - the browser does this for you, but when you access it directly, you need to URLEncode yourself. You have to encode each parameter *name*, then add the `=` without encoding, then encode the value, then add the `&` without encoding, etc. Don't encode just *part* of the value or just *part* of the name.

Comment: Works when I also do:
            URLEncoder.encode(baseUrl, "UTF-8");
            URL myUrl = new URL(baseUrl);
            String response = restTemplate.getForObject(myUrl.toURI(), String.class);